# textbox.value not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The following is a simple javascript code to set a value into a textbox. But, it doesn't seem to work. I am not able to find the flaw. Also, the javascript is working only in IE and not in Chrome/Firefox. How do I get out of this trouble?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function reportValue()
        {
            var form = document.getElementById("billgen");
            var radioArray = form["time"];
            var months;
            for(var i=0;i<radioArray.length;i++)
            {
                if(radioArray[i].checked)
                {   
                    months = radioArray[i].value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(months == "1")
            {  
                e=31*100;
                form["total"].value = e;    
                //document.getElementById("total").value = e; => not working as well
                return true;
            }  

           else{
            alert("Are you sure the instructor is " + months + "?\nYou may be underestimating the instructor!");
            return false;
            }   
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Bill Generation</legend>
            <form id="billgen" method="post">
                <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="1" checked /> 1 Month </label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="3" /> 3 Month </label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="6" /> 6 Month </label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="12" /> 1 Year </label>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="reportValue();" />
                <p>        
                    <input type="text" id="total" name="total" />
                </p>
            </form>         
        </fieldset>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById["billgen"]` is not correct usage, you're not invoking the method but attempting to look up a property. Instead, invoke `document.getElementById("billgen")`

Comment: @PaulS. I tried that  as well. It doesn't work still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicing on a `<input type="submit"/>` causes the page to reload, so instead of "submit", either use the [`<button>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) element or use an `<input type="button"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with `getElementById(` instead of `getElementById[`: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8d68aabL/1/) and it works.

Comment: It worked. But the value is set and cleared automatically. and even in the jsfiddle, an error is thrown, CRLF verification failed. What is that?

Answer (score 0):

Just move your code to the end of your html, just before the `</body>` and it should work, I think the problem is that you are asigning the form to a variable before the form even exists.

Comment: It worked. But the value is set and cleared automatically. and even in the jsfiddle, an error is thrown, CRLF verification failed. What is that?

Comment: Try using a type button instead of submit like the answer below mine sugested. The click on a button of type submit automatically trigger page reload